# Why below function is not being optimized by using delegate?

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, expression-trees

I have below function to send the log. And I used to have a reflection approach.(The commented code inside the function). I would like to optimize the reflection, after some investigation online, I ended with below solution and it still took me the same time. (20 secs for processing 100k log records). Can anyone help/guide me why?

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<object, object>> _delegateCache = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>();

    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]> _propertyCache =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]>();

    public static string ToJson(this object obj)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create LogEventInfo object. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="ex"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static LogEventInfo ToLogEventInfo(this ILogItem data, string message, Exception ex = null)
    {
        var eventInfo = new LogEventInfo();

        if (ex != null)
            eventInfo.Exception = ex;

        if (data != null)
        {
            data.EventMessage = message;
            data.LogTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
            data.LogId = Guid.NewGuid();


            //var properties = data.GetType().GetProperties();
            //foreach (var property in properties)
            //{
            //    eventInfo.Properties[property.Name] = property.GetValue(data, null);
            //}

            //Cache the delegate with expression tree.
            if (!_propertyCache.TryGetValue(data.GetType(), out var propertyInfo))
            {
                var properties = data.GetType().GetProperties();
                var delegateProperties = new Func<object, object>[properties.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
                {
                    delegateProperties[i] = GenerateGetterLambda(properties[i]);

                    var propertyName = properties[i].Name;
                    var propertyValue = delegateProperties[i].Invoke(data);
                    _delegateCache.TryAdd(properties[i].PropertyType, delegateProperties[i]);

                    eventInfo.Properties[propertyName] = propertyValue;
                }
                _propertyCache.TryAdd(data.GetType(), properties);
            }
            else
            {
                var properties = propertyInfo;

                var length = properties.Length;
                for (var i= 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    if (_delegateCache.TryGetValue(properties[i].PropertyType, out var propertyDelegate))
                    {
                        eventInfo.Properties[properties[i].Name] = propertyDelegate.Invoke(data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                eventInfo.Message = message;
        }

        return eventInfo;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combined with expression tree to futher improve the performance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="property"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static Func<object, object> GenerateGetterLambda(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        var expParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "instance");
        var expInstance = Expression.TypeAs(expParameter, property.DeclaringType);
        var expProperty = Expression.Property(expInstance, property);
        var expPropertyObj = Expression.Convert(expProperty, typeof(object));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(expPropertyObj, expParameter).Compile();
    }
}
```

Comment: For better performance you have to Compile function which accepts `LogEventInfo` and object `Func<LogEventInfo, object>`, cache it by object Type. Then just invoke one delegate instead of invoking CountOfProperties delegates.

Answer (score 0):

You are using double cache, once for properties and secend for getters.

Try something like this:

```
public static LogEventInfo NewToLogEventInfo<T>(this T data, string message, Exception ex = null) where T : ILogItem {
    var eventInfo = new LogEventInfo {
        Exception = ex
    };

    if(data != null) {
        data.EventMessage = message;
        data.LogTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
        data.LogId = Guid.NewGuid();

        DataInfoHelper.FillProperties(data, eventInfo);
    } else {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            eventInfo.Message = message;
    }

    return eventInfo;
}
```

and Helper class with generic method:

```
public static class DataInfoHelper {
    public static void FillProperties<T>(T dataItem, LogEventInfo logEventInfo) where T : ILogItem {
        DataInfo<T>.GetInstance().AppendValues(dataItem, logEventInfo.Properties);
    }
}
```

generic cache class

```
public class DataInfo<T> where T: ILogItem {
    private static DataInfo<T> instance;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>> propertyGetters;

    public void AppendValues(T logItem, Dictionary<string, object> properties) {
        WaitForGenerateGetter();
        foreach(var getter in propertyGetters)
            properties.Add(getter.Key, getter.Value(logItem));
    }

    public static DataInfo<T> GetInstance() {
        return instance ?? new DataInfo<T>();
    }

    private DataInfo() {
        instance = this;
        lock(this) {
            if(propertyGetters != null)
                return;
            var getProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.GetProperty);
            var getters = new Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>>(getProperties.Length);
            foreach(var property in getProperties)
                getters.Add(property.Name, GenerateGetter(property));
            propertyGetters = getters;
        }
    }

    private void WaitForGenerateGetter() {
        if(propertyGetters == null) {
            lock(this) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private Func<T, object> GenerateGetter(PropertyInfo property) {
        //Func<T, object> t = (T instance) => (object)property.GetValue(instance);            
        var instanceParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "instance");
        var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(instanceParameterExpression, property);
        var castExpression = Expression.Convert(propertyExpression, typeof(object));
        var returnParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
        var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(castExpression, instanceParameterExpression, returnParameterExpression);
        return lambdaExpression.Compile();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could populate a static dictionary in a static constructor, no locking required. Since this type is unlikely to be initialised if it is not needed.

Comment: You're probably right, I did it as Silgenton, will only be initialized if needed at least once